# How does a Statement Function 'make no definite assertion about anything'?

Tags: logic

<sub>Source: p 456 (chart), 457 (Quote), *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014) by Patrick Hurley</sub>

> [image]
>
> In these examples, the expressions [...] [that I coloured in green], and so on are called statement
> functions. A **statement function** is the expression that remains when a quantifier is
> removed from a statement. It is a mere pattern for a statement. ***It makes no definite assertion
> about anything in the universe, has no truth value, and cannot be translated as
> a statement.***

1. How are the 2 italicised sentences correct? They appear to debase and denigrate the green which (to me) appear truly important, because:
2. am I correct that the green expressions match, and so assert, the red ('S are P')?
   I know that the purple (and not the green) explains the Universal Quantifiers 'all' and 'no'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting observation that you make, since, on the surface, the two "statement functions" appear to *express* contradictory things.

Your headline question "How can a statement function make no definite assertion about anything?" is answered with the obvious response : because that is how the author has defined a statement function in the quoted text. When one reads a statement function such as Sx ⊃ Px, one needs to ask "what x?" before one can impose any meaning, and this is what the quantifiers do.

As the author states, the green expressions (statement functions) **cannot be translated as a statement**, so according to the author's intentions it is not correct to say than the green expressions "match, and so assert" the statement "S are P".  Indeed, according to the quoted text, a statement function makes **no assertion**.

The author's example shows how quantification of a "statement function" can impose meaning onto the resulting statement, and that different quantifiers can yield quite different symbolic translations and meanings.

**EDIT**

If you are familiar with the concept of function in mathematics, then just as a mathematical function has no *meaning* without a domain, in logic a statement function has no meaning until its domain is specified by quantification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry to bother you, but [this subsequent of mine](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/31175/8572) may matter because the author subsequently seems to say that Statement Functions DO mean something, in a subsequent chapter (unfortunately) about which I could not have known when I wrote the question above.

Comment: +1. Thank you. Answer your edit at the bottom: Yes; I know the basics about a Function in maths, but I am no set theorist.