# What 'certain liberties' inject meaning to Statement Functions?

Tags: logic

<sub>Source: p 465, *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014) by Patrick Hurley</sub>

> [...] 5. Py ⊃ Cy    3, 4, Hypothetical Syllogism
>   6. (x)(Px ⊃ Cx)     5, Universal Generalisation [...]
>
> As noted earlier [[on p 457  which I questioned earlier]](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/31129/8572), the expressions in lines 3, 4, and 5 are called ***statement functions***. As
>   such, they are mere patterns for statements; they have no truth value and cannot be
>   translated as statements. Yet if we take `certain liberties`, we might characterize line 5 as
>   saying
>   “If ***it*** is a P, then ***it*** is a C["],
>   where “***it***” designates any item at random in the universe.
>   Line 6 can then be seen as reexpressing this sense of line 5.

1. What does the author mean by `certain liberties`?

2. 
I am most confused; does the above quote appears to contradict p 457?
What is the final answer on whether Statement Functions mean anything?

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my previous answer.  As per your request, I have posted some thoughts on this question in my answer below.

Comment: @NickR +1. You are most welcome. It is I who must thank you. To fortify my comprehension, please allow me to reread both your answers tomorrow.

Comment: The thing to keep in mind here is the distinction between the formal and the informal reading of statement functions.  Even not knowing what S and P denote, we can assign some informal meaning to Sx &sup; Px, namely that if x is S then it is also P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the author suggests that "we take certain liberties", he means "if we drop the rigours of our logical formalism and look at statement 5 in a non-rigorous, hand-wavy, informal way", then we can translate statement 5 accordingly.

To best understand the **formal** concept of a statement function, the key word to focus on here is "function".  As I noted in [my previous answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/31130/8572), a function is only fully defined when we have assigned it a domain (i.e., a universe of discourse).

For example, if **S** denotes "is divisible by 4" and **P** denotes "is divisible by 2", then **Sx** ⊃ **Px** can only be assigned a meaning when we know the domain/universe from which x is chosen. Otherwise, from a formal point of view, x is just a typographical symbol and the statement function is just (what the author refers to as) a pattern. If the universe is the set of whole numbers then the meaning is obvious and the statement **(x) Sx** ⊃ **Px** is true, while the statement **(x) Px** ⊃ **Sx** is false.  Of course, from an informal point of view, we can assign a meaning once we know what **S** and **P** denote.

Therefore, the example given here does not contradict the formal statement of page 457, since the treatment given here is an informal one.

Comment: I modified your post marginally and am sorry for any offense; I thought to link to the answer aforesaid. Please feel free to refine.

Comment: @LePressentiment No problem.  Both the edits are improvements on the originals.  Thanks. N